# I get EOFException while trying to get response from the server

Tags: java, android

I use a PrintWriter out object. I write data out.println(some data) and close it with a out.close

```
URL url = new URL(myurl);
URLConnection connection = null;
PrintWriter out = null; BufferedReader br = null; connection = url.openConnection(); connection.setDoOutput(true);
out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream()),true);
while(iterations) { 
    //print data on writer 
    out.println(object);
 } 
 //closig print writer
 out.flush(); 
 out.close(); 
 //Response from server
 br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream())); // Get Exception in //this line EOF Exception
 String temp;
 while(temp = br.readLine() !=null) { 
     //do something 
 }
 br.close();
```

Comment: Upload your code with the error code.

Comment: End file exception..? maybe at the server.. are you coding server end too ..?

Comment: post your source code, your logcat and discribe your problem not only in one sentense!

Comment: Some time this code work and some time it gives eofexception. When it gives eof exception no data posted to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
URL url = new URL(myurl);
 URLConnection connection = null;
 PrintWriter out = null; BufferedReader br = null; connection = url.openConnection(); connection.setDoOutput(true);
 out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream()),true);
 while(iterations)
     { 
//print data on writer 
out.println(object);
 } 
//closig print writer
 out.flush(); 

//Response from server
 br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream())); // Get Exception in //this line EOF Exception
 String temp;
 while(temp = br.readLine() !=null)
{ //do something }
 out.close();
```

Have a look at the code, you just had to put out.close instead of br.close at the end.